# How do I get the json nested object?

Tags: json, react-native

I am new to React Native, and want to get the nested object from json. Here is my code. And I can get succesfuly data.phone but always get this if I try to get data.name.title or etc.

**undefined is not an object**

Here is my code.

```
class Dictionary extends Component {
    // Initialize the hardcoded data
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.state = {
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
                'John', 'Joel', 'James', 'Jimmy', 'Jackson', 'Jillian', 'Julie', 'Devin'
            ])
        };

        fetch('http://api.randomuser.me/?results=50')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                //return responseJson.movies;
                console.log( responseJson.results );
                this.setState({
                    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson.results),
                    loaded:false,
                })

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View
                style={styles.container}>

                <ListView
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={(data) =>
                        <View>
                            <Text>
                                {data.phone}
                            </Text>
                                <Text>
            {data.name.title}
        </Text>   
                        </View>
                    }
                    renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator} />}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

How can I get the name.title?
Thanks
And here is the json data from randomuser.me

```
{"results":[{"gender":"female","name":{"title":"miss","first":"abby","last":"perkins"},"location":{"street":"9542 highfield road","city":"ely","state":"herefordshire","postcode":"J9 2ZJ"},"email":"abby.perkins@example.com","login":{"username":"redcat541","password":"1026","salt":"LIsOByBg","md5":"2890bf50a87289f7f3664840e2c47fe3","sha1":"1944896ba6cc78ad32dcf927dc5c9226d2f9e050","sha256":"9013be19c91195788009cc545f8a2be4494687dc29b155513022ce9157b73785"},"dob":"1959-05-20 07:03:41","registered":"2006-07-10 01:28:56","phone":"0101 716 4694","cell":"0738-649-138","id":{"name":"NINO","value":"BC 35 80 42 Q"},"picture":{"large":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/54.jpg","medium":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/54.jpg","thumbnail":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/54.jpg"},"nat":"GB"}],"info":{"seed":"2e632bbc13c85cb2","results":1,"page":1,"version":"1.1"}}
```

when I console.log(data.name) I get this {"title":"miss","first":"abby","last":"perkins"} and so on on every Iteration i get different names. So i guess there is no need in data[0] - it looks like everything is ok with getting the proper data object. just need to access data.name.title but no luck with it. Sorry, it pretty confusing for me this time as every prev time there were no problems with any json obj or array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the constructor, but I don't know why.

Just pass an empty array and it will work.

```
this.state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([])
};
```

You can do this too:

```
this.state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([{name: "Ahmed"}])
};
```

See here for more information:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listviewdatasource.html#clonewithrows

Comment: @SERG Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Its because your `{data.name.title}` is directly in view tag. Place that in `<Text>` component like this:

```
 <ListView
    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
    renderRow={(data) =>
        <View>
            <Text>
                {data.phone}
            </Text>
            <Text>
                {data.name.title}
            </Text>   
        </View>
    }
    renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator} />}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, now I get the "undefined is not an object"

Comment: This is just parsing JSON, and React is not any different. Maybe there is no name inside your json, console.log(data) in your renderRow and see what your data is.

Comment: in this example https://medium.com/differential/react-native-basics-how-to-use-the-listview-component-a0ec44cf1fe8 they just use props.name.last - and it works, so it is not "no name" but it does not work for me for some reasons

Comment: So what do you get when you log data in renderRow? I repeat myself again, getting nested object in json is the same everywhere. Based on the data you get from server your results is an array so you should do {data[0].name.title} based on that data

Comment: when I console.log(data.name) I get this {"title":"miss","first":"abby","last":"perkins"} and so on on every Iteration i get different names. So i guess there is no need in data[0] - it looks like everything is ok with getting the proper data object. just need to access data.name.title but no luck with it. Sorry, it pretty confusing for me this time as every prev time there were no problems with any json obj or array

Comment: That's odd. You should be able to get title by data.name.title then. I will check your code on my machine.